# How do you attach a behavior in the ViewModel, using MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

For the purpose of the question, lets say I have a simple XAML view with a Grid on it. The view has a view model, as per MVVM. An architect has decided that the view model must not have any reference to the view.

On my view model I have a DataTable object which is used as Data Source for the Grid in the View. I'm adding several columns dynamically on the view model. If I wanted to attach a behavior to these columns, after they are created on code, how would you do it?

Comment: Find out more about Blend SDK, Interaction/Interacitivity namespaces.

Comment: Note that you can *never* truly have no references to the view due to the event system used with `INotifyPropertyChanged` (I have actually had someone argue with me about this). You don't want strongly typed references to the view, but it is possible to take the principle too far...

Comment: Honestly I would reference the view from the viewmodel and add the behavior. I know it's not what you want, but there isn't much of an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register for the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event on the `DataGrid`.

Inside you have access to the newly generated column through the `Column` property of the `DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs` object.

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    // Customization: e.Column. ...
}
```

Comment: This would mean the VM has access to the view or that the view would have code in the code behind, both of which the author has stated he does not want.

Comment: @Kelly Where is it specified that the OP does not want to have code behind in the view, the only constraint I see (and it's a really reasonable one) is "An architect has decided that the view model must not have any reference to the view"?...

Comment: @Pragmateek Thank you, although it's not the answer I was expecting, it's the nearest working solution I can get.